# Why do I always return position 10 in my code?

Tags: c++

In my program for sorting an array of strings, I always get a position of 10 when binary searching a name. Why does this occur?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXNAMES = 20;

void readArray(string names[])
{
    ifstream inFile("names.txt");
    string line;
    int counter = 0;

    if (!inFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << endl << "Cannot locate file names.txt" << endl;
        exit(0);

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Succesfully opened \"names.txt\" file." << endl;
    }

    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        names[counter++] = line;
    }

    inFile.close();
}

void displayArray(string names[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXNAMES; i++)
    {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void selectionSort(string names[])
{
    int i, j, minIndex;
    string minString;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXNAMES - 1; i++)
    {

        minIndex = i;
        minString = names[i];

        for (j = i + 1; j < MAXNAMES; j++)
        {
            if (minString.compare(names[j]) > 0)
            {

                minString = names[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }

        if (minIndex != i)
        {
            string temp = names[i];
            names[i] = names[minIndex];
            names[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void sequentialSearch(string names[], string name)
{
    bool found = false;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXNAMES; i++)
    {
        if (name.compare(names[i]) == 0)
        {
            found = true;
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
        cout << "The name is not found." << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "The name is found at index: " << index + 1 << "." << endl;
}

void bubbleSort(string names[])
{
    string temp;
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXNAMES - 1; j++)
    {

        for (int i = j + 1; i < MAXNAMES; i++)
        {
            if (names[j].compare(names[i]) > 0)
            {
                temp = names[j];
                names[j] = names[i];
                names[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int binarySearch(string names[], string name)
{
    int l = 0;
    int r = MAXNAMES - 1;

    while (l <= r)
    {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        int res = 0;

        if (name == names[m])
            res = 0;
        if (res == 0)
            return m;

        if (name > (names[m]))
            l = m + 1;
        else
            r = m - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    string names[MAXNAMES];
    readArray(names);
    cout << "Array before sort:" << endl << endl;
    displayArray(names);
    cout << "Array after selection sort is:" << endl << endl;
    selectionSort(names);
    displayArray(names);
    string nameToSearch;
    cout << "Enter a name to (sequential) search for: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, nameToSearch);
    sequentialSearch(names, nameToSearch);
    string choice;
    cout << endl << "Replace first element of the array \"" << names[0] << "\" with \"" << nameToSearch << "\" Yes or No: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, choice);

    if (choice.compare("Yes") == 0 || choice.compare("yes") == 0)
    {
        names[0] = nameToSearch;
    }

    bubbleSort(names);
    cout << endl << "Array after Bubble Sort is:" << endl;
    displayArray(names);
    cout << "Enter a name to (binary) search for: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, nameToSearch);
    int index = binarySearch(names, nameToSearch);

    if (index == -1)
        cout << endl << "The name is not found." << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "The name is found at position " << (index + 1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the input file used for the code:

names.txt

```
Collins, Bill
Smith, Bart
Allen, Jim
Griffin, Jim
Stamey, Marty
Rose, Geri
Taylor, Terri
Johnson, Jill
Allison, Jeff
Looney, Joe
Wolfe, Bill
James, Jean
Weaver, Jim
Pore, Rob
Rutherford, Rose
Javens, Renee
Harison, Rose
Setzer, Cathy
Pike, Gordon
Holland, Beth
```

Comment: Did you try running your code line by line in a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) while monitoring the values of all variables?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel   Even "`printf` debugging" would have been a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `binarySearch`, you have this sequence:

```
    int res = 0;

    if (name == names[m])
        res = 0;
    if (res == 0)
        return m;
```

Since `res` will always be zero when that 2nd `if` is reached, it will always return on the first time thru the loop.

You can remove `res` completely, and just replace all that with

```
    if (name == names[m])
        return m;
```